# Confusion regarding definition of functions almost everywhere

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

In Folland's Real Analysis,(Second Edition, Page 54) he proves the following proposition for an arbitrary measure space $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$:

If $f,g \in L^1(X,\mu)$, then $f = g$ a.e $\Leftrightarrow$ $\int_{X}|f-g|d\mu = 0$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $\int_{E}f = \int_E g, \forall E \in \mathcal{M}$

Following this, he says 'For the purposes of integration, it makes no difference if we alter functions on null sets....' basically saying we can treat $\mathbb{R}\cup\{-\infty,\infty\}$ valued functions as $L^1$ functions too. I have to ask the following here:

1. How does an arbitrary redefinition of the function make sense unless the measure space is complete? For if $f= g$ a.e (on $N^c$), and $g$ is measurable, then we have $f^{-1}{(\alpha,\infty)} = f^{-1}{(\alpha,\infty)}\cap N^c \cup f^{-1}{(\alpha,\infty)}\cap N = g^{-1}(\alpha,\infty)\cap N^c\cup f^{-1}{(\alpha,\infty)}\cap N$. So unless arbitrary subsets of null sets are there in $\mathcal{M}$, something like this doesn't seem to work.
2. The same issue is present in Folland's proof of DCT. He has proved that pointwise limit of measureable functions which converge almost everywhere in a complete measure space is measureable, and every measurable function in a complete measure space has a measureable representative in the original $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$. Based on these results, he is again assuming that for an arbitrary measure space, if $f_n \rightarrow f$ a.e, then $f$ is measurable as we can 'redefine' $f$. What does this mean precisely? Presumably he's saying we can go to the completion, and since $f$ is $\overline{\mathcal{M}}$ measurable there get a representative of $f$ that is $\mathcal{M}$ measurable and which is equal to $f$ a.e(w.r.t both $\mu,\overline{\mu}$); but then he promptly proceeds to integrate $f$ in the original measure space? Isn't it completely false in that sense? Or is he talking about $[f]$ secretly(equivalence class)?

Comment: @peek-a-boo I understood the first part of what you said, but I don't see how it solves the issue no. 1. With regards to DCT, so I am correct in guessing that the $f$ in the proposition as stated by Folland and the one he is actually integrating are two different things?

Comment: 1. If the measure is not complete, then 'For the purposes of integration, it makes no difference if we alter functions on null sets....' provided we keep the function measurable.

2. For DCT proof for arbitrary measure spaces,  if $f_n \rightarrow f$ a.e, then $f$ may not be  measurable, but we can always find a measurable function $g$ such that $g=f$ a.e.. Note that we also have  $f_n \rightarrow g$ a.e. So, we can always assume $f$ is measurable (as we can 'replace' $f$ by $g$, if needed).